# How to load multiple SSL certificates in Java KeyStore?

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have two SSL certificate files. The first is marked as "OU=Certificate Authority" and the second one is marked as "OU=Root Certificate." Our C++ application loads both these certificates for proper client/server handshake.

I now need to use these certificates in my Android code. I have been able to read these certificates successfully using `CertificateFactory.generateCertificate()` method.

Next, I need to store these certificates in a keystore. Here is the sample code I found:

```
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
```

I am confused on how to store the root certificate. Do I just call `setCertificateEntry()` again for the second certificate and pass in some random alias name?

I see another method on KeyStore called `setEntry`. Should I be using this method instead? Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call it again with another alias.

Example:

```
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("debug", ca2);
```

Comment: @AstroCB. Actually, it does.

Comment: That simple. With the change, looks like my client is able to connect to the server. Guess the alias names mean nothing for client/server handshake. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AstroCB Thre is no critique here, and I am in no need of clarification from the author, nor of absurd comments from people who clearly have neither read the question nor understood the topic.